# Is there a way to insert a parameter or reorder parameters in ADO test cases?

Tags: testing, parameters, azure-devops, test-plan

I have created a test cases with several different parameters, and realized that I skipped one while writing it. I don't see an obvious way to insert a new parameter or reorder the columns. I would like to keep them in order without deleting every row below it and redoing everything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you referring to the situation shown below? If so, then we can't insert or reorder parameters here.

[image]

If you want to insert the parameter , you need to click **Convert to shared parameters**.
On the Shared Parameter page, you can insert parameters by right clicking and selecting **Insert row**. Inserting column by clicking "**+**" button. After the modification, you can add the parameter set to the test case by clicking **Add a shared parameter set**.

[image]
[image]

If you want to insert parameter column,in addition to doing it on the Shared Parameter page. You can also reorder it in **Steps** use "@"+ parameters name and move it use the arrow.
[image]